# Samsung Galaxy S2 - sound notification does not always work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, audio, google-talk, notification-bar

my samsung galaxy s2 (android 2.3.4, kernel 2.6.35.7, build gingerbread.xwki4) does not always beeps when I get google talk messages (I'am not using social hub, just native Talk app) also it does not display message on the top of the screen

I can't figure out when the notification works and when it doesn't work, is it that because I already answered to the person? but I would like to be still notified if I don't have gtalk opened

if a notification does not work for a certain contact it still works for new people starting conversation, however it is not clear for me when it should beep and when it is intentional that it does not beep

is there a way to configure notification to always beep when a certain application isn't opened?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you receive the message?

If you don't get a beep nor a top screen message but you get the message once you re-enter on the talk application (after a small delay) maybe the problem is that you lose the connection with the server.